# Julia: Parametric types with inner constructor: new and typeof

Tags: julia

Trying to understand parametric types and the `new` function available for inner methods. The manual states "special function available to inner constructors which created a new object of the type". See the section of the manual on **new** [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#new) and the section of the manual on **inner constructor** methods [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/constructors/#man-inner-constructor-methods).

Consider an inner method designed to calculate the sum of `x`, where `x` could be, say, a vector or a tuple, and is given the parametric type `T`. A natural thing to want is for the type of the elements of `x` to be inherited by their sum `s`. I don't seem to need `new` for that, correct?

```
struct M{T}
    x::T
    s
    function M(x)
        s = sum(x)
        x,s
    end
end


julia> M([1,2,3])
([1, 2, 3], 6)

julia> M([1.,2.,3.])
([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 6.0)

julia> typeof(M([1.,2.,3.]))
Tuple{Vector{Float64}, Float64}
```

**Edit:** **Correction!** I intended to have the last line of the inner constructor be `M(x,s)`... It's still an interesting question, so I won't correct it. How does `M(x,s)` differ from `new{typeof(x)}(x,s)`?

One usage of `new` I have seen is in combination with `typeof()`, something like:

```
struct M{T}
    x::T
    s
    function M(x)
        s = sum(x)
        new{typeof(x)}(x,s)
    end
end

julia> M([1,2,3])
M{Vector{Int64}}([1, 2, 3], 6)

julia> M([1.,2.,3.])
M{Vector{Float64}}([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 6.0)
```

What if wanted to constrain `s` to the same type as `x`? That is, for instance, if `x` is a vector, then `s` should be a vector (in this case, a vector of one element). How would I do that? If I replace the last line of the inner constructor with `x, new{typeof(x)}(s)`, I get the understandable error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Int64 to an object of type Vector{Int64}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the rules:

1. If you are writing an outer constructor for a type `M`, the constructor should return an instance of `M` by eventually calling the inner constructor, like this: `M(<args>)`.
2. If you are writing an inner constructor, this will *override* the default inner constructor. So you must return an instance of `M` by calling `new(<args>)`.

The `new` "special function" exists to allow the construction of a type that doesn't have a constructor yet. Observe the following example:

```
julia> struct A
           x::Int
           function A(x)
               A(x)
           end
       end

julia> A(4)
ERROR: StackOverflowError:
Stacktrace:
 [1] A(::Int64) at ./REPL[3]:4 (repeats 79984 times)
```

This is a circular definition of the constructor for `A`, which results in a stack overflow. You cannot pull yourself up by your bootstraps, so Julia provides the `new` function as a way to circumvent this problem.

You should provide the `new` function with a number of arguments equal to the number of fields in your struct. Note that the `new` function will attempt to convert the types of its inputs to match the declared types of the fields of your struct:

```
julia> struct B
           x::Float64
           B(x) = new(x)
       end

julia> B(5)
B(5.0)

julia> B('a')
B(97.0)

julia> B("a")
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object
of type Float64
```

(The inner constructor for `B` above is exactly the same as the default inner constructor.)

When you're defining parametric types, the `new` function must be provided with a number of parameters equal to the number of parameters for your type (and in the same order), analogously to the default inner constructor for parametric types. First observe how the default inner constructor for parametric types is used:

```
julia> struct Foo{T}
           x::T
       end

julia> Foo{String}("a")
Foo{String}("a")
```

Now if you were writing an inner constructor for `Foo`, instead of writing `Foo{T}(x)` inside the constructor, you would replace the `Foo` with `new`, like this: `new{T}(x)`.

You might need `typeof` to help define the constructor, but often you don't. Here's one way you could define your `M` type:

```
struct M{I, T}
    x::I
    s::T

    function M(x::I) where I
        s = sum(x)
        new{I, typeof(s)}(x, s)
    end
end
```

I'm using `typeof` here so that `I` could be any iterable type that returns numbers:

```
julia> typeof(M(1:3))
M{UnitRange{Int64},Int64}

julia> g = (rand() for _ in 1:10)
Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#5#6"}(var"#5#6"(), 1:10)

julia> typeof(M(g))
M{Base.Generator{UnitRange{Int64},var"#5#6"},Float64}
```

Note that providing the parameters for your type is required when you are using `new` inside an inner constructor for a parametric type:

```
julia> struct C{T}
           x::Int
           C(x) = new(x)
       end
ERROR: syntax: too few type parameters specified in "new{...}" around REPL[6]:1
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this super detailed answer. It's helping me a great deal! Just above where you write "I'm using `typeof` here so that `I` could be any iterable type that returns numbers", can `typeof(s)` be equivalently replaced by `T`? And what if i want `x::Float64`?  I change `{I,T}` to `{T}`, suppress `where I` and write `new{Float64, typeof(s)}(x,s)`, but that's a "too many type parameters" error. If it's not asking too much, would you comment on that? Thanks!

Comment: If you replace `typeof(s)` by `T` (and that's the only change you make), then you will get a `ERROR: UndefVarError: T not defined` error when you call the constructor, because you've just pulled `T` out of thin air. In other words, you have to define the type variables before you provide them to `new`. In the example for the type `M`, the type variable `I` is defined by capturing the type of the input argument to the constructor.

Comment: The number of parameters that you provide to `new` has to be the same as the number of parameters that the type has (and in the same order). I've edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I meant to say, "you have to define the type variables *somewhere within the constructor* before you provide them to `new`."

Comment: Thanks Cameron. So by "constructor" you mean just the inner method? Thus it's not enough for `new` to have `M{I,T}` and `s::T` inside the `struct`,  `new` also needs to be given `typeof(s)`: `new` does not see what's inside the `struct`! Am I understanding it now?

Comment: Is it an implication of "`new` must have the same number of parameters as the type" that if you use `new` then every field of the `struct` must be parameterized? In other words, if you have a `x::Float64` instead of `x::I` in the `struct`, then you cannot use `new` at all in the inner method. Is that right? Thanks!

Comment: Think of the inner constructor as being a normal function that just happens to be written down inside the struct definition, except for two differences: a) the inner constructor that you define overrides the default inner constructor, and b) the inner constructor has access to the `new` function. (Outer constructors and other functions do *not* have access to the `new` function.) Just like all other variables, type variables have to be bound to a value before you use them. So the type variables that you provide to `new` have to be bound to some value before you provide them to `new`.

Comment: The inner constructor does not "see" the type parameters in the struct definition. Even if it did see them, it wouldn't help, because the type parameters in a struct definition are "free parameters" --- they're not bound to any value. For example, in `struct A{T} end`, the type parameter `T` is a free parameter.

Comment: In response to a couple of your questions: `new` is not optional. You must use it in every inner constructor definition. ...And no, the fields of the struct do not have to be parameterized. The number of parameters and the number of fields are independent of each other. If I wanted to, I could define a struct with 4 parameters and only 1 field.

Comment: This is getting a bit lengthy for the comment section, so if you have more questions, feel free to create a new Stack Overflow question, or ask on Discourse. :)

Comment: Thank you Cameron. You have helped me so much. I feel like the master of `free` now. I'm pretty sure some of what you wrote would be a great addition to the docs. The docs are always clear when you already know what they're telling you, but when you don't, even a small detail can prevent you from understanding a bunch of other things. The main hurdle for me was understanding that "The inner constructor does not "see" the type parameters in the struct definition. Even if it did, it wouldn't help because they are not bound to any value: they're abstract." Thanks Cameron!

Answer (score 1):

Remember, a constructor is designed to *construct* something. Specifically, the constructor `M` is designed to construct a value of type `M`. Your example constructor

```
struct M{T}
    x::T
    s
    function M(x)
        s = sum(x)
        x,s
    end
end
```

means that the result of evaluating the expression `M([1 2 3])` is a tuple, not an instance of `M`. If I encountered such a constructor in the wild, I'd assume it was a bug and report it. `new` is the internal magic that allows you to actually *construct* a value of type `M`.

It's a matter of abstraction. If you just want a tuple in the first place, then forget about the structure called `M` and just define a function `m` at module scope that returns a tuple. But if you intend to treat this as a special data type, potentially for use with dynamic dispatch but even just for self-documentation purposes, then your constructor should return a value of type `M`.

Comment: Thanks Silvio. I realize I intended to have `M(x,s)` in the inner constructor! However, your answer is super useful as it is, so I don't intend to edit the question. I'd be grateful if you could comment on the difference between returning `M(x,s)` and `new{something}(x,s)`. Thanks!

Comment: I believe, in your case, there isn't much of a difference. The difference would apply if you were overriding `M(x, s)` (in which case you cannot call the *original* `M(x, s)` on account of having just replaced it). You can think of each inner constructor as implicitly calling `new` unless you override it to do something different. In your case, your `M(x)` calls `M(x, s)` which was generated by the Julia runtime and implicitly calls `new(x, s)`.